# How to edit and change sidebar menu item on jeroennoten admin-lte laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, adminlte

I tried to edit on config/adminlte.php but did'nt works. How to change or edit menu item on sidebar? I was integrate jeroennoten admin-lte packages on laravel 5.8

Answer (score 4):

run

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider"`

so adminlte publish their config. After that you will get a file named `adminlte.php`. the path for the file is `config/adminlte.php`.

In this file You will found an array. Then goto menu index, which is your menu list. Update that portion to update your menu.

reference : https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#51-menu

If you you update menu portion but menu not updating then, its because of your config cache. To handle this problem you should run the command

`php artisan config:clear`